# CKEditor - Image Upload Provide Specific Path

Tags: ckeditor

I have spent some time digging into the docs, and my head is now spinning. I want to use the image upload feature of CKEditor, but very explicitly I need to:

1. provide the path when the page loads that I want the file(s) saved to (based on a content_id field), such as: "rootfolder/content/images/in_content5" where '5' is the content_id ...
2. turn off the ability to 'link' for the image (although that's not as important to me).

It is unclear to me how to do either of these, the first is the most important to me. I need this to be dynamic for file management purposes among other things. I wouldn't be surprised if someone has previously asked this, but with hundreds of posts already, it's hard to find anything here.

Comment: The path where the files are saved is controlled by your server side script, not CKEditor. You must adjust it there. I don't understand your second question (and it's bad to put 2 issues in a single Stackoverflow post)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the second issue -- I was looking at the default file dialog that seems to come up with the image button. There's an option in the dialog to use a "link" to a URL for an image outside the main site (a bad idea for most websites). 

Regarding the first, I couldn't find anything that gave a clear example of how to get my file upload code to work with CKEditor. I finally gave up ...